# react-native run-android ; SDK location no found, but it exists in the path

Tags: android, android-studio, react-native

According to the [react-native docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#2-install-the-android-sdk), I have installed A`ndroid 8.0 (Oreo)` and the rest of the instructions. The only difference is that I have defined the path varibales in `.bashrc` and not `.bash-profile`. when I want to run my react-native application I face the `Build failed with an exception.`

the log looks like below:

```
sudo react-native run-android
Starting JS server...
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && ./gradlew installDebug)...
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible and 1 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable.
```

the project built for me does not contain the `local.properties`. but I already have ANDROID_HOME in the Path.

```
$ printenv | grep Android
ANDROID_HOME=/home/amir/Android/Sdk
PATH=/home/amir/Android/Sdk/tools:/home/amir/Android/Sdk/tools/bin:/home/amir/Android/Sdk/platform-tools:/home/amir/Android/Sdk/emulator
```

Answer (score 4):

As you mentioned `local.properties` not exist by default and you should add it to project.

1. Go to your React native Project -> Android
2. Create a file local.properties
3. Open the file
4. paste your Android SDK path like below

   ```
   in Windows sdk.dir =    C:\\Users\\USERNAME\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\sdk
   in macOS sdk.dir = /Users/USERNAME/Library/Android/sdk
   in linux sdk.dir = /home/USERNAME/Android/Sdk
   ```

Replace `USERNAME` with your user name

Now, Run the `react-native run-android` in your terminal.

Comment: So you mean there is no way that cli recognize the path?

Comment: And now I get /bin/sh: 1: adb: not found

Comment: or with an ANDROID_HOME environment

Comment: @Amir-Mousavi I got it, Now you should define `adb` path to system environment  variables

Comment: system variable/ ANDROID_HOME is updated and also sdk is set in local.properties but still shows the error!

Comment: For Windows, mind the double slashes though! Worked for me!